# How to show an hidden element by clicking on another element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's a fiddle :

http://fiddle.jshell.net/ggw6hqsj/1/

Here's my problem (for example) :

When the first button is clicked, the second is hidden.
But I don't know how to make reappear the hidden button when the first button is clicked once again.

Any idea ? Thanks.

Comment: `.show` is the opposite of `.hide`.  That is in an example in the jQuery docs for `hide`:  http://api.jquery.com/hide/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way in your code would be to change

```
$('.button2').hide();
```

to

```
$('.button2').toggle();
```

for button 1 and 2.

[fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/ggw6hqsj/2/)

Answer (score 3):

`$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.button1').click(function(){
        $('.button2').toggle();
    });
});`

http://fiddle.jshell.net/ggw6hqsj/3/

Answer (score 1):

Probably the simplest change to your existing code would just be to use [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) instead of `.hide()`:

```
$('.button2').toggle();
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need to show the clicked button and hide the other one.

try this

```
function activateButton(num){
    var activeButton = ".button" + num;
    var otherButton = ".button" + (num === "1" ? "2" : "1");
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $(activeButton).show();
    $(otherButton).hide();      
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.button1').click(activateButton("1"));
    $('.button2').click(activateButton("2"));
});
```